# XTEA fragment: Which is better layout?

Tags: c++, coding-style, code-formatting

I am doing a University assignment in which part of the assignment is to implement the XTEA block cipher in C++. We are allowed to use Internet sources, so I went to the [XTEA Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA#Implementations) and found the code there.

As I was copying it^ I was thinking about code style/layout. I initially had

```
data_first32 = ( (( data_last32 << 4 ) ^ ( data_last32 >> 5 )) + data_last32 ) ^
        ( sum + key[ sum & 3 ] );
```

(Note: those are 2 lines not 1 line wrapped)

However I then thought maybe it would be easier to read if it was:

```
data_first32 = 
        (
            (
                ( data_last32 << 4 ) 
                ^ 
                ( data_last32 >> 5 )
            ) 
            + 
            data_last32 
        ) 
        ^
        ( sum + key[ sum & 3 ] );
```

The latter one seems to be to be (slightly) easier to read, however it just seems 'wrong'.

Which is the better (Readability) style?

Why does the latter one seem 'wrong'?

^ Not using copy & paste, as I wanted to go through it manually and I wanted better variable names.

Comment: The second one is *extremely* confusing to me. Note that you don't have to compute it all in one go. Perhaps you can compute each part separately and combine them at the end?

Comment: @Bo Persson The 2nd one has the advantage that the level of indentation shows the precedence of the various nestings of the expression. And it's familiar to Boost.MPL users.